# How can I apply forms.ModelChoiceField to a model-form? (Django)

Tags: django, forms

I am a complete beginner with little understanding of widgets etc, I'm using a model-based form that needs to have a drop-down selection box for dietary preferences. this is what I tried to do earlier (obviously wrong):

```
class Register(models.Model):

      dietry_preferences = forms.ModelChoiceField( queryset = "none", "vegetarian", "vegan", "halaal", "kosher", empty_label = "none")
```

can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: ModelChoiceField doesn't care at all what kind of form it is on. However, what you have here is a *model*, not a form. You can only use form fields on a form, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ModelChoiceField` is related to forms. It is unclear if you want to build a form or a model. Therefore, for a model:

```
class Register(models.Model):
    PREFERENCES = (
        ('vt', "vegetarian"),
        ('vg', "vegan"),
        ....
    )    
    dietry_preferences = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=PREFERENCES)
```

Then you would build a modelform [appropriately](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Reference: [Django documentation, choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices)

Otherwise, for a form:

```
class Register(forms.Form):
    PREFERENCES = (
        ('vt', "vegetarian"),
        ('vg', "vegan"),
        ....
    )    
    dietry_preferences = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PREFERENCES)
```

Reference: [Django documentation, ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield)